# Javascript array contents are defined as empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, 3d

i used a console.log for a 3d array and this is its contents

[image: i used a console.log for a 3d array and this its contents]

for the second its contents are clear

[image: for the second its contents are clear]

```
for(let mmm = 0; mmm < NumOfPatterns;mmm++)
{
    for(let i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    {
        for(let j = 0; j < 36; j++)
        {
            patterns[mmm][i][j] = 0;
            console.log(patterns[mmm][i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I use this function just to define every value to 0

Comment: Show how you're creating the array in the first place. It looks like you're creating it by assigning elements in the middle without filling in the earlier elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check if the arrays exist:

```js
const NumOfPatterns = 10
const DEFAULT_ARR_LENGTH = 36

let arr3d = []

// checking if the referenced elements exist
// if not, create them on the first iteration
for (let mmm = 0; mmm < NumOfPatterns; mmm++) {
  if (typeof arr3d[mmm] === "undefined") arr3d[mmm] = []
  for (let i = 0; i < DEFAULT_ARR_LENGTH; i++) {
    if (typeof arr3d[mmm][i] === "undefined") arr3d[mmm][i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < DEFAULT_ARR_LENGTH; j++) {
      arr3d[mmm][i].push(0)
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr3d)
```